# Xcode storyboard isn't visible; is it possible to zoom/pan the canvas?

Tags: xcode, ios5, storyboard

I wouldn't ask if I couldn't find it anywhere else, but I've run into a problem. I have a complete storyboard built in Xcode, but I've lost it on the screen. Pressing the +/- buttons in the bottom right zoom in and out, but nothing shows up. I know the app is there because it runs fine, but all of my views are off the screen and I have no idea how to get them back. And since I'm on a desktop, there's no way to pan (maybe the same issue happens on a laptop?)

How do I get my storyboard back?

I searched for a "zoom all" in the menus but can't find one.

This is so frustrating. Grrr. I can't work on my storyboard until I can find it on the canvas. I can't find it on the canvas because I can't pan and have no idea where it is.

Comment: Must have been an XCode bug. Restarted and it fixed it. Annoying....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your storyboard file => Open As => iOS Storyboard